# materialize css lebal right to left - cant position it on a right place

Tags: frontend, materialize, right-to-left

I build a website in Hebrew and use MaterializeCss. Every input I make a label is floating to the left side. I could not find  any documentation about it and would be very happy to some help.

im use `<html dir="rtl"></html>`, its not help for label tag.
also tried text align property, float etc.
thanks!!

Comment: I believe you want `<body dir="rtl">…</div>`, not  `<html …`

Comment: nope... its make the same outcome... and its work across all my site Except in the 
form-input fields

Comment: form input fields need "rtl" marks for themselves. As for layout that contains the input fields, I am not sure.